# Build curl URl using variables

Tags: shell, for-loop, variables, curl

I'm trying to use curl to loop over a list if IDs and send a DELETE to cancel each one

I'm getting stuck on injecting the variable into the url for curl to use

I'm starting/testing using something simpler to begin with

This works fine and outputs the list of IDs in $queued_builds

```
for build in $queued_builds; do echo "$build"; done

230
231
232
233
```

But if I try to inject/make them part of the URL, it fails (just using echo here to simulate/check the URL value)

```
for build in $queued_builds; do echo "https://www.test.org/$build"; done

for build in $queued_builds; do echo "https://www.test.org/$build"\; done
for>
```

Can the URL be built in this way?

Many thanks

Comment: Sure. There's nothing `curl`-specific in this question; you can build strings in your shell scripts using variables. You say, "it fails"; can you provide more details on exactly how things are failing? Does your `for` loop with the `echo` statement produce the output you expect?

Comment: `queued_builds` may have hidden characters in it. What does `printf '%q\n' "$build"` show?

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like my array of numbers is incorrect.

`printf '%q\n' "$queued_builds"

243$'\n'244$'\n'245$'\n'246$'\n'247$'\n'248$'\n'249`

They are being captured as a single string with new lines, rather than an array of multiple x3 digit strings

Had not considered this.

I need to examine the command that is populating the array I think.

`(az pipelines runs list --status notstarted | grep _apis/build/Builds | cut -d "/" -f9 | grep -o '[0-9]*')`

Thanks for the pointer to where I need to focus.